# What do the commands for matrix brackets stand for?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

Usually, many TeX commands are abbreviations of some English words. For instance, `\hline` stands for *horizontal line*, `\frac` stands for *fraction*, `\neq` stands for *not equal*, etc.

What do the commands for matrix brackets (`\vmatrix`, `\pmatrix`, `\bmatrix`) stand for? I guess pre-letter `v` means *vertical* (for determinants), but I have no idea about the other two.

I'm eager to know the longhands since this helps me work more naturally and faster.

Comment: I guess `p` stands for _parenthesis_ and `b` for _bracket_

Comment: @Vincent yes (you could make that an answer)

Comment: `b` stands for "boring" and `p` for "pretty". ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In `pmatrix`, `p` stands for *parenthesis*: the delimiters used are ( and ).
- In `bmatrix`, `b` stands for *bracket*: the delimiters used are [ and ], which are generally called *square brackets*.
- In `Bmatrix`, `B` stands for *brace* or *bracket*: the delimiters used are { and }, which are called *braces*, *curly brackets* or *curly braces*.
- In `vmatrix` and `Vmatrix`, `v` and `V` both stand for *vertical*: the delimiters used are single and double vertical lines respectively. As @Teepeemm pointed out, recall that `amsmath` also has `\vert` and `\Vert` commands, which similarly produce single and double vertical lines respectively.